# display all unique date available first

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA script which takes input from user to perform find and replace, want to display all the unique date available first

I have written this VBA script to perform find and replace but I want to add one more functionality here,it should display me the list of all the distinct dates available in the column first and after that we can perform find and replace*

```
Sub dateupdation()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Date
Dim rplc As Date

fnd = InputBox("Enter date")
rplc = InputBox("Enter updated date")

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Does your Excel version support the `UNIQUE` formula? Otherwise, you can loop and store unique values in a `Scripting.Dictionary`.

Comment: Let me check and try looping also will get back for any help, thanks for suggestion Ben

Comment: Is the code located in the `ActiveWorkbook` or in another workbook? Where will you put the unique values (worksheet, column)? Where will you get them from (a column in each worksheet)? Are there dates outside the columns? If not you should restrict the search (replace) to those columns. Please do clarify.

Comment: located in Active workbook, unique values should pop up in the screen and so that we know what all unique dates are available and then ask user input for replace

Comment: Sub dateupdation()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Date
Dim rplc As Date
ActiveSheet.Range("C3:C29").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("H3"), Unique:=True


fnd = InputBox("Enter date")
rplc = InputBox("Enter updated date")

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht

Columns("H").Delete
End Sub

Comment: ''''Above code kind of helped me but it is filtering for a single sheet on the workbook if i do want to filter multiple sheets in workbook how do we achieve that'''any suggestion pls